# Firefox javascript becomes unresponsive warning

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox

I realized that the firefox browser gives warning when we make a ajax call which takes more time to respond/the function in javascript takes more time to complete its execution.

I read in an article it is due to the properties in firefox. Something like it should wait only these many seconds for an javascript to complete its execution.

Can anyone clearly explain me about that? 
How can we solve this via program?

Comment: I think you need to show an example to be replicated for others to test.

Comment: I have noticed that Firefox's SVG implementation is dramatically slower than contemporary versions of Chrome and IE.  Karthik, you should definitely provide an example -- it's a worthy topic.

Comment: I don't think that Ajax will produce such behavior. Normally what causes Firefox to hang or warn is an infinite-loop

Comment: @AdrianSalazar Sorry, it is a warning.. i wrongly typed it as error. Thanks or correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the length of time Firefox waits for script execution by:

1. Typing about:config into the address bar
2. Searching for the **dom.max_script_run_time** preference name.
3. Setting the dom.max_script_run_time value to something other than the default.  (currently 10 seconds, at least in Firefox 30.0)

However, I'd strongly suggest you look at the script you're executing for further problems first.   Note that 10 seconds is not how long it takes for the script to run, but rather how long the script has been *unresponsive* for - much worse.

More information on how the dom.max_script_run_time parameter works can be found here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.max_script_run_time